# serving static files with Nginx and Puma Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, puma

I am trying to configure Nginx + Rails + Puma with unix sockets but I was not able to serve my asests. I have following configurations I would appreciate if someone could point what is missing. My Nginx configuration;

```
upstream my_app {
  server unix:///var/run/my_app.sock;
}

server {
  listen 8080;
  server_name _; 
  root /var/www/plantmonitorweb/public; # app location

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://my_app;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }

  # this one is from Rails guides
  location ~ ^/assets/ {
    expires 1y;
    add_header Cache-Control public;

    add_header ETag "";
  }
}
```

In production.rb

```
  config.public_file_server.enabled = false
  config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect'
```

puma.rb is not changed. I am running puma server with following command;

```
puma -e production -b unix:///var/run/my_app.sock
```

I run those in remote machine (Rasberry Pi to be specific) Puma runs fine it seems nginx is hitting my server but when I open chorome console I see following

```
 GET http://192.168.1.35:8080/pack/app.js
```

I check this file under public/pack and it is there.

My Nginx configuration is in /etc/nginx/conf.d/ which is included inside of Nginx.conf (include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf)

Answer (score 3):

In rails 5, react js files are served under `public/pack/`. So we need to add those locations to be served statically as well as assets folder. So added following location to my nginx configuration.

```
 location ~ ^/(assets|packs)/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires 1y;

    add_header Cache-Control public;
    add_header Last-Modified "";
    add_header ETag "";
  }
```